# How do you get an Auth0 access token in a React Router v6.4 loader and action?

Tags: typescript, react-router, auth0

How do you get access to an Auth0 access token inside React Router v6.4 `actions` and `loaders` so you can call a secured API?

I've tried to curry the `getAccessTokenSilently()` method to the loader but I can't call the `useAuth0()` hook outside a component (my routes are created outside a component [as recommended by the react router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router)). I can't call `useAuth0()` inside the loader for the same reason: it's not a component.

I tried putting the routes inside a component anyway (moving the routes shown in my code below to an `<App/>` component) but that results in errors from `useAuth0()` about it having to be called from within an `Auth0Provider`.

The official [Auth0 guide to React Router v6](https://developer.auth0.com/resources/guides/spa/react/basic-authentication) hasn't been updated to use `createBrowserRouter` and doesn't use loaders in their secure API example.

This seems like a fundamental need in any React Router v6.4 application and yet I've never been able to find an example that shows how to do it. Surely someone has done this before?

**Update: Thanks to the assistance of Drew this works! The below code is a full working version of this.**

**Auth0ProviderWithNavigate.tsx**

```
interface Auth0ProviderWithNavigateProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const Auth0ProviderWithNavigate = ({
  children,
}: Auth0ProviderWithNavigateProps) => {
  if (
    !(
      ENV.VITE_AUTH0_DOMAIN &&
      ENV.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID &&
      ENV.VITE_AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL
    )
  ) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={ENV.VITE_AUTH0_DOMAIN}
      clientId={ENV.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: ENV.VITE_AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
```

**AuthenticationGuard.tsx**

```
import { withAuthenticationRequired } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { PageLoader } from "./PageLoader";

interface AuthenticationGuardProps {
  component: React.ComponentType<object>;
}

export const AuthenticationGuard = ({
  component,
}: AuthenticationGuardProps) => {
  const Component = withAuthenticationRequired(component, {
    onRedirecting: () => <PageLoader />,
  });

  return <Component />;
};
```

**main.tsx**

```
const root = document.getElementById("root");

root &&
  ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <AppContextProvider>
        <Auth0ProviderWithNavigate>
          <AppTheme>
            <App />
          </AppTheme>
        </Auth0ProviderWithNavigate>
      </AppContextProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

**App.tsx**

```
const App = () => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

  const router = useMemo(() => {
    return createBrowserRouter([
      {
        children: [
          {
            path: "/",
            element: <WelcomePage />,
            errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
          },
          {
            children: [
              {
                id: "edct",
                path: "/edct",
                element: <AuthenticationGuard component={Edct} />,
                errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
                loader: AirportCodesLoader({ getAccessTokenSilently }),
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default App;
```

**AirportCodesLoader.tsx**

```
import { ActionFunction } from "react-router";

const cleanCodes = (codes: string | null): string | null => {
  if (!codes) {
    return null;
  }
  return codes
    .split(",")
    .map((code) => code.trim())
    .join(",");
};

interface AppLoader {
  getAccessTokenSilently: () => Promise<string>;
}

export const AirportCodesLoader =
  ({ getAccessTokenSilently }: AppLoader): ActionFunction =>
  async ({ request }) => {
    const url = new URL(request.url);

    console.log(await getAccessTokenSilently());
    return {
      departureCodes: cleanCodes(url.searchParams.get("departureCodes")) ?? "",
      arrivalCodes: cleanCodes(url.searchParams.get("arrivalCodes")) ?? "",
    };
  };
```

Comment: I don't see a path forward where `Auth0Provider` is rendered *within* the router so `Auth0ProviderWithNavigate` works as a layout route while simultaneously be rendered *above* the `RouterProvider` so the `auth0` context value can be passed to route loaders. I think you either have to give up the `onRedirectCallback` capability so `Auth0Provider` can be lifted higher in the ReactTree, or give up using route loaders and do the data fetching in the routed components where `useAuth0` hook can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! At least I know I'm not crazy now :)

Comment: Ok I moved the Auth0ProviderWithNavigate up and the RouterProvider is now rendered inside of it, and I'm not using onRedirectCallback. The base authentication seems to work fine.

I'm still unclear on how I can obtain getAuthTokenSilently() and pass it to the loader. The route is created in main.tsx so I can't use the hook. Do I just make my route in a component despite the docs saying not to do that?

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include your newer implementation? I think the basic gist is that the component rendering the router that is now under `Auth0Provider` can use the `useAuth0` hook to access the auth0 context and can pass this to route loaders, which will now necessarily need to curry it. If this doesn't make sense then seeing what you are working with I can try to provide a clearer example.

Comment: Ahhh that nudge plus re-reading the react page, I see where I misunderstood where to call createBrowerRouter. I will do some refactoring tomorrow to bring back an App component that makes the routes instead of main.tsx doing it outside a component and that should work. I'll report back with updated (hopefully working!) code.

Comment: I've updated my post with the current code. I'm still not seeing how I can call `useAuth0` to get the function to pass to my loader/actions. Per the react router docs `createBrowserRouter` should be called outside a component ("create your router outside of the React tree with a statically defined set of routes"), so how do I use a hook to get a function to pass in to the action/loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, while it is the common practice to declare the router configuration outside the React tree, this is just a recommendation. In this case you can create it inside the `App` component so it can close over an instance of the `auth0` context value to be passed to route loaders. The route loaders that need to receive the `auth0` context will need to curry that parameter.

Example:

```js
const AirportCodesLoader = (auth0) => ({ params, request }) => {
  ... loader logic ...
};
```

```
const App = () => {
  const auth0 = useAuth0();

  const router = React.useMemo(() => { // <-- memoize router reference
    return createBrowserRouter([
      {
        children: [
          {
            path: "/",
            element: <WelcomePage />,
            errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
          },
          {
            children: [
              {
                id: "edct",
                path: "/edct",
                element: <AuthenticationGuard component={Edct} />,
                errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
                loader: AirportCodesLoader(auth0), // <-- pass auth0 to loader
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);
  }, [auth0]); // <-- auth0 external dependency

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};
```

Comment: Ok thanks. That's how I wanted to do it but the react router docs scared me off  I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: OMG IT WORKS I CAN'T BELIEVE IT  Thank you so much for your patience and assistance with this. I'm updating the code in the post shortly so it's there anytime someone else needs it in the future.